# Django filter queryset in reverse relation

Tags: python, django

**Code I'm working with:**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    from_who = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent')
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recieved')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Can I display in template User.recieved messages only with new = True when I'm using request.user **not** context? If yes, how?

Comment: What part do you have problems with: using the reverse relation from the user or adding a filter statement to it?

Comment: You mean, I have to create a custom template filter?

Comment: Well you could do that. You could also use a custom manager or a model method, but the most simple way would be to prepare the data in your view code and pass it to the context.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to prepare that data in all views that exists. I have problem with using custom menager in that example, would you tell me how to write that manager?

Comment: Please add your related view and template code!

Comment: I don't understand you. I don't have any related view and in template snippet I want do display how many messages belongs to requested User that are new in every single view in every single page. Thats why I want to use request.user.

Comment: And I like to see what you have done trying to solve the problem so far. On SO it is expected that you show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question - you want to show all new message to the logged in user without adding any additional context to the view? Try this (and note that I changed the spelling of "received":

```
{% for message in request.user.received.all %}

    {% if message.new %}
        {{ message }}<br />
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is looking an answer:

```
#models.py
class Message(models.Model):
from_who = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent')
to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recieved')
text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
new = models.BooleanField(default=True)

new_messages = NewMessageManager()

#managers.py
class NewMessageManager(models.Manager):

def new_messages(self):
    return super(NewMessageManager, self).get_queryset().filter(new=True)

#template.html
{% if request.user.recieved.new_messages %}
  <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ request.user.recieved.new_messages.count }}</span>
{% endif %}
```